Find command in system path from Java on macOS
From Java I need to execute a user-installed command (let’s call it abc) on macOS. However when running
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"abc", "--argument"});

it cannot be found as Java seems to inherit a limited system $PATH (it works when calling it from the system shell). I figured out
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"sh", "-c", "$SHELL -c 'abc --argument'"});

works on my device (tested with zsh and fish as shells). However on a different device that has bash set as the system shell, it cannot be found. I had hoped that calling $SHELL would load the login path.
Both of these do not work:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
processBuilder.start();

What is the correct way to run a command in the System $PATH from Java?

ps faux | grep 'abc' doesn't show it?

ps faux on my macOS install yields ps: illegal option -- f
usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]] [-u] [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]] ps [-L]

Yes, looks like you need to prepend -

seems to inherit a limited system $PATH : Why do you write seems, if you can easily verify it by yourself. Just print inside your Java application the value of the environment variable PATH, and execute it like this: echo $PATH; java YOUR_APPLICATION, and then compare the two PATH values, in what respect they differ.

@g00se ps -faux yields ps: No user named 'x'. This is macOS. It works fine on Linux.

@user1934428 well, it does inherit a limited $PATH. The trouble is that it is launched as a plugin from another Mac app. Somewhere in this process, the $PATH gets changed.

If you don't know the PATH offered by a parent process, it is pointless to talk about a disappeared PATH in Java. If it is a plugin, it could well be that the process for this plugin fiddles with the PATH; or that in turn the parent process of this app is doing it. But you can change the environment of your own process. Just set the PATH environment inside your Java Application.

I came to stack overflow to ask how to load the system environment $PATH. I failed at finding a solution online, what is the canonical way to do this?

I don't know what load the system environment $PATH is supposed to mean. Basically, the system sets a default PATH for each application to be started. It depends on the OS version, but most likely it is /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin. If you use your own program - for instance some shell - you configure it by adding directories to the PATH. Since the PATH sits in the environment, it is passed on to its child processes, but of course each child process has the liberty to fiddle with it, before passing it to its grand children.

On my Mac (macOS Monterey), the components of the initial path are found in the file /etc/paths, so if you want to explicitly retrieve the "system path", you could get it from there. But note that there is no guarantee that it will work that way over all MacOS versions.


You need to learn how to use ps on a Mac. 2. You are making statements/assumptions about paths which are simply not correct, such that you have an 'XY problem'. If you run a system command from Java, most diagnostics will only show the java process, unless you have maximum verbosity enabled, which shows all the arguments passed in the process in question


To rephrase the question: I want to execute an executable file that is in the normal system $PATH but not in the $PATH accessible to my Java process. So I want the ability to execute said file. Ideally I'd like a Java Runtime or ProcessBuilder object, that sources its environment from the system. Alternatively, a shell command to execute in the same system-call that resets the path will do. The path the file is in varies by user and is most likely (But not necessarily) /usr/local/bin or /opt/homebrew/bin. I want a solution that is robust to any install location that is in the $PATH.


To rephrase the question: I want to execute an executable file that is in the normal system $PATH but not in the $PATH accessible to my Java process. So I want the ability to execute said file. Ideally I'd like a Java Runtime or ProcessBuilder object, that sources its environment from the system. Alternatively, a shell command to execute in the same system-call that resets the path will do. The path the file is in varies by user and is most likely (But not necessarily) "/usr/local/bin" or "/opt/homebrew/bin". I want a solution that is robust to any install location that is in the $PATH.

The problem is that "the normal system $PATH" is not a well defined thing, and is certainly not easy for a Java (or a C, C++, Python) program to determine it.
It is easy to get the PATH environment variable that was passed to the Java command.  Just call System.getEnv("PATH").  But the problem is:

It isn't (necessarily) the current value of PATH in the shell (or subshell, or executable) that ran the java command.

It isn't (necessarily) the initial value of PATH of the user's login shell after running the standard shell init files.

It isn't (necessarily) the value of the shell's PATH before running the user's various shell init files.

For Bourne and compatible shells, the initial values of the PATH and other environment variables typically come from the "/etc/profile" file and other files that it references.  But not always.  It is complicated.  Read the INVOCATION section of man bash to get a feel for what could happen.


In short "the normal system $PATH" isn't a well defined thing.  The PATH assembled and exported in "/etc/profile" is probably the best approximation to what you are talking about, but in order to access that you need to (in effect) "source" that file into a shell.
In addition, you don't know if the user (or his admin) has installed your application's executable into one of the directories that would be on the "the normal system $PATH".  People do unexpected things for various reasons.  (And not necessarily bad reasons.)  You shouldn't try to second guess them.

So what to do?
Well, to my mind, the pragmatic solution is:

Implement a command line option or config property or something that the user can use specify the absoilute path to the command you want to run.

If the user doesn't use that option / property, assume that you will be able to find the command via the PATH variable that was passed to the java command.

If neither of the above works, print a helpful error message and let the user sort it out.


You could also get a value for PATH from a command line option or config file.  Or even allow the user to provide a shell init file ... as per @g00se's answer.

If you're looking for a per-user customization of $PATH, then you could do something like this perhaps:
/* Contents of named file in /tmp are:
export PATH=/opt/lib:$PATH
*/

public class PathExtender {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String[] cmdAddToPath = {
            "/bin/bash",
            "-c",
            "source /tmp/add-to-path && echo $PATH"
        };
        new ProcessBuilder(cmdAddToPath).inheritIO().start();
    }
}

The path of /opt/lib now gets prepended to $PATH for me
